# Switching between two apps in appium iOS

Tags: automation, automated-tests, appium, ios-ui-automation, appium-ios

I have a testcase where in an iPhone I have to 
1. Perform a task in app A. 
2. Switch to Safari browser and perform a task
3. Switch back again to App A and continue other tasks

Currently I can perform 1 & 2 & then switch back to App A but I cannot perform any tasks in App A after switching from the safari browser. What I did is as follows.

First of all to launch the app A I used the following code

```
public void createAppiumDriver() throws MalformedURLException, InterruptedException {
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "iPhone 7 Plus");
capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "iOS");
capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "11.2"); 
capabilities.setCapability("autoWebView", true);
capabilities.setCapability("app", getProperties().getProperty("appURL"));
capabilities.setCapability("autoAcceptAlerts", true);
capabilities.setCapability("useNewWDA", true);
capabilities.setCapability("startIWDP",true);
iosDriver = new IOSDriver(new URL("http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);}
```

To switch from my app to Safari I started a new session using the following code to switch to safari

```
public void openSafari() throws MalformedURLException {
DesiredCapabilities capabilities2 = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities2.setCapability("deviceName", "iPhone 7 Plus");
capabilities2.setCapability("platformName", "iOS");
capabilities2.setCapability("platformVersion", "11.2");
capabilities2.setCapability("browserName", "Safari");
capabilities2.setCapability("autoAcceptAlerts", true);
capabilities2.setCapability("useNewWDA", true);
iosDriver2 = new IOSDriver(new URL("http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities2);
iosDriver2.get("https://www.gmail.com");}
```

The issue now I have is to switch back to App A again from the safari browser to perform some tasks for that at the moment I have created a new session again as follows

```
public void switchToNutrifix() throws MalformedURLException, InterruptedException {
DesiredCapabilities capabilities3 = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities3.setCapability("deviceName", "iPhone 7 Plus");
capabilities3.setCapability("platformName", "iOS");
capabilities3.setCapability("platformVersion", "11.2"); //Replace this with your iOS version
capabilities3.setCapability("autoWebView", true);
capabilities3.setCapability("app", getProperties().getProperty("appURL"));
capabilities3.setCapability("autoAcceptAlerts", true);
capabilities3.setCapability("useNewWDA", true);
capabilities3.setCapability("startIWDP",true);
iosDriver3 = new IOSDriver(new URL("http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities3);}
```

The issue now is that the app A opens again from Safari but it cannot identify the elements in the app. I even changed the context correctly to webview but still it cannot perform any tasks in App A after switching from Safari browser. Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong here or another alternative way to do this switch.

The error I usually get is

```
May 09, 2018 6:43:42 PM org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions findElement
WARNING: WebDriverException thrown by findElement(By.xpath: //div[@class='login-content purpose']/h2)
org.openqa.selenium.remote.SessionNotFoundException: A session is either terminated or not started (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
```

and the appium logs display

```
debug] [iOS] No key id found. Choosing first id from page array
[debug] [iOS] Page change not referring to currently selected app, ignoring.
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class SwitchBtnAppsiOS {

public AppiumDriver<RemoteWebElement>iosDriver;

public DesiredCapabilities createAppiumDriver()
    throws MalformedURLException, InterruptedException {
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
    capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "iPhone 7 Plus");
    capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "iOS");
    capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "11.2"); 
    capabilities.setCapability("autoWebView", true);
    capabilities.setCapability("app", getProperties().getProperty("appURL"));
    capabilities.setCapability("autoAcceptAlerts", true);
    capabilities.setCapability("useNewWDA", true);
    capabilities.setCapability("startIWDP",true);
    return capabilities;
}


public DesiredCapabilities openSafari() 
    throws MalformedURLException {
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
    capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "iPhone 7 Plus");
    capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "iOS");
    capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "11.2");
    capabilities.setCapability("browserName", "Safari");
    capabilities.setCapability("autoAcceptAlerts", true);
    capabilities.setCapability("useNewWDA", true);
    return capabilities;
}

public void switchBetweenApps() throws MalformedURLException, InterruptedException
{
    DesiredCapabilities nativeAppCaps = createAppiumDriver();
    iosDriver = new IOSDriver<>(new URL("http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub"), nativeAppCaps);

    /**
     * Perform the actions on native app
     */

    DesiredCapabilities webCaps = createAppiumDriver();
    iosDriver = new IOSDriver<>(new URL("http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub"), webCaps);
    iosDriver.get("https://www.gmail.com");

    /**
     * Perform the actions on safari browser 
     */

    // Again switch to native app
    iosDriver = new IOSDriver<>(new URL("http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub"), nativeAppCaps);
}
}
```

1. Where ever you are using the driver instances pass the latest instance of driver.
2. Use RemoteWebElement instead of MobileElement if that is the case.

Answer (score 1):

There is a better way of switching b/w iOS apps instead of creating driver session again and again as suggested in above answer

```
IOSDriver driver = new IOSDriver<>(new URL("http://localhost:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);

try {
HashMap<String, Object> args = new HashMap<>();
args.put("bundleId", SWITCH_APP_BUNDLE_ID);
driver.executeScript("mobile: launchApp", args);

/*
TODO code for switch app
*/


// Now reactivate  AUT App
args.put("bundleId", AUT_APP_BUNDLE_ID);
driver.executeScript("mobile: activateApp", args);

/*
TODO code for AUT App
*/
} 
finally {
// quit driver     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since **with XCode 9 Appium support multiple sessions**, I suggest using **2 simultaneous sessions**: app and safari:

1. Create driver for native app (e.g. `driver1` object)
2. Do want you need in app, keep driver instance alive

Hint: you may put it in background: 
`driver.runAppInBackground(Duration.ofMinutes(1));`

3. Create driver for safari (e.g. `driver2` object)
4. Do want you need in safair and close `driver2` if you don't need it
5. Continue using `driver1` for native app

Comment: I tried using driver.runAppInBackground(5); but what it does is the app goes background waits for 5 seconds and pops up again without moving to the safari browser. Only after it pops up after 5 seconds it goes to safari. So I used driver.runAppInBackground(-1) so it doesn't automatically popup again. But I don't know how to bring back the app after using safari. I tried using  driver.launchapp() but it just reinstalls the app & it cannot identify the elements in the app.

Comment: did you try crating 2 instances of driver? thats the only way because with appium/XCUITest you most likely cannot inspect 2 apps in single session.